# How can i make a player stop moving when it touchs a collider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i was wondering if there is a way to make a player move infinitely with just one click and just stop when colliding with another collider.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a global property:

```
bool movePlayer = false;
```

In FixedUpdate method you can detect a mouse click and change movePlayer to true, and move the player if it values true:

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        movePlayer = true;

    if (movePlayer) {
        //move the player here, maybe with Translate method
    }
}
```

With OnTriggerEnter method you can detect the collision and change movePlayer to false:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    //you can check for some particular object or avoid this if
    if (other.gameObject.name == "SomeObject")
        movePlayer = false;
}
```